# Did people ever pour drinks on the floor to reject a toast or indicate an end to civilities?

Tags: war, diplomacy, royalty

In a fantasy book called "Jack of Shadows" by [Roger Zelazny](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roger_Zelazny#Awards) I read this:

*A disgraced member of a ruling party is being forced to ceremonially drink to the coronation of the new king, but instead defiantly lifts his cup, proclaims himself the new king, & drinks. Everyone else in the room pours their drink upon the floor.*

Spilling wine on floors almost certainly wouldn't be acceptable in the present day, but the act makes me curious as to when it might have been commonplace & in what situations it might have been done. Disapproval of a wedding? A breakdown in negotiations between diplomats? A fight erupting amidst a dining hall?

Comment: I think to keep this from being too broad, you should remove the last sentence and limit this to the deliberate action of rejecting a toast.

Comment: One of the reasons why it is extremely impolite nowadays are carpets and other floor coverings. Ever tried to get a wine stain out of a carpet? It's less difficult on a wooden or stone floor.

Comment: Lars, it was a fantasy book called "Jack of Shadows" by Zelazny. I was wondering if this detail had any historical truth to it.

Jos, yes, I'm sure it would have been less taboo upon a stone floor, and yes, I've gotten wine out of carpets. Pour salt on it right away!

Comment: Pouring drink on the ground (rather than on floors), as a gesture to honor the dead  (a way to share the drink with the dead), is  present in many cultures and is to be related to the religious act of [libation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libation). I think it's probable that the "fantasy" event is just a fantasy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think that pouring drinks on the floor is rejecting a toast or ending civilities. I read in a article that: "pouring one out refers to “the act of pouring liquid (usually an alcoholic beverage) on the ground as a sign of reverence for friends or relatives that have passed away." So this would indicate the meaning behind pouring drinks on the floor.

https://vinepair.com/wine-blog/libations-and-the-ancient-history-of-pouring-one-out/

Comment: I have of course heard of this custom as well, yet think you're probably right in that this particular scene is likely nothing more than Zelazny's story.